# Python: Print data while waiting for input

Tags: python, sockets, loops

Writing a chat program and am looking for the ability for it to print messages that are being received when they are received while the user can enter a message to the other person. Currently the program sends message to other computer then receives the other computer's message and then repeats.

```
import sys
import socket as so
import platform
from socket import *
import string
import base64
import os
import random

dmi = 0
lmi = 0 
host = ""
checkcode = ''.join(random.choice('0123456789QWERTYUIOPLKJHGFDSAZXCVBNMasdfgjhklpoiuytrewqmnzbxvc') for i in range(16))
BLOCK_SIZE = 32
hostl = raw_input("> Input IP of computer message will be sent to: ")
port = 13000
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
addrl = (hostl, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)
addr = (host, port)
addrl = (hostl, port)
while dmi == 0:
    datal = raw_input("Enter message to send or type 'exit': ")
    UDPSock.sendto(datal, addrl)
    if datal == "exit":
        UDPSock.close()
        dmi +=1
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    print "Received message: "+ data
print "Done!"
```

Don't ask about the un-needed libraries that I have imported, this is a test script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn how to use multiple threads (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm). One thread waits for user input, while the other receives the messages and prints them.